# Using sed command to match parent folder and immediate subfolder

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a linux command that prints the following:

```
folder/subfolder1/file1.txt
folder/subfolder2/file1.txt
folder/subfolder2/file2.txt
folder/subfolder3/sub-subfolder3/file1.txt
```

My goal is to use `sed` to print the following result instead:

```
folder/subfolder1
folder/subfolder2
folder/subfolder2
folder/subfolder3
```

However, I'm not able to just keep the main folder and the immediate subfolder, I'm just able to remove the file name

```bsh
's/\(folder\/.*\)\(\/.*\)/\1/'
```

, which prints

```
folder/subfolder1
folder/subfolder2
folder/subfolder2
folder/subfolder3/sub-subfolder3
```

Comment: What is the command that produces that initial list?  Note that pathnames are, generally speaking, not limited to single lines. So if you want to have a solution that is valid for all valid pathnames, you may want to modify that command that produces that list, rather than post-processing a text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to print paths only up to the depth of `subfolder`. In
that case you can use `cut`:

```
your_command | cut -d/ -f1-2
```

or `awk`:

```
your_command | awk -v FS='/' '{print $1 "/" $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.*` after `folder\/` matches *greedily*, leaving only the final `/` to match in your second capture group.

Instead, you can use `[^/]*` to match everything up to the next separator:

```
sed 's/\(folder\/[^/]*\)\(\/.*\)/\1/'
```

or (since you don't actually use the second group)

```
sed 's/\(folder\/[^/]*\)\/.*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed it can be done as follows:

```
your_command | sed -n 's|/|\n|2g;P'
```

Or, in case of the POSIX sed editor to print the desired data. Convert all slashes to newlines, then revert the first one and print upto the first newline.

```
your,_command |
sed -n '
  y/\//\n/
  s|\n|/|;P
'
```